# how to detect the origin of a request in socket.io

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, socket.io, amazon-eks

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  if (socket.request.connection.remoteAddress === "::ffff:127.0.0.1") {
    socket.on(
      `msg-relay-chat`,
      (msg, hit, receiver) => {
        socket.to(LIVE_CHAT_ID[hit]?.[receiver]).emit("msg-received-chat", msg);
      }
    );
  }
});
```

The `if` block above `if (socket.request.connection.remoteAddress === "::ffff:127.0.0.1") { }` is meant to detect requests coming from the backend API of my app, ie. only the backend API can relay certain messages.

This current setup works in development in my local environment.

Now I am about to deploy the socket.io APP and the backend API app onto a kubernetes cluster on AWS EKS.

Let's suppose that the `Service` name of the backend API is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-api
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend-api
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 2201
```

How do I tweak the condition of the `if` block, `if (socket.request.connection.remoteAddress === "::ffff:127.0.0.1") { }`, so that the socket.io pod can detect the origin of the requests and that if it is from the `backend-api` service, then it can relay the messages inside of the `if` block.

Comment: I'd suggest having a different socket.io port that is not accessible from the outside world and only support your API requests on that port.  Then, there is no confusing at all about where they came from.  You can use all the same code for both ports, just tag incoming requests with a flag when they arrive on the API port (that isn't open to the outside world) so downstream in your processing you unequivocally know whether this is an internal request or an outside request.

Comment: When I say "not accessible from the outside world", I mean that traffic on that specific port is blocked by a proxy/firewall when coming from the outside world so that the only requests that can reach that port are from inside the firewall.  You could also use some sort of authentication scheme for internal requests.